# Support Vector Machine on R and WEKA

Tags: r, machine-learning, svm, weka

My data generated strange results with svm on R from the e1071 package, so I tried to check if the R svm can generate same result as WEKA (or python), since I've been using WEKA in the past.

I googled the question and found one that has the exact same confusion with me but without an answer. [This is the question](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/SVM-differences-between-R-Weka-Python-td4673586.html).

So I hope that I could get an answer here.

To make things easier, I'm also using the iris data set, and train a model (SMO in WEKA, and svm from R package e1071) using the whole iris data, and test on itself.

**WEKA parameters**:

```
weka.classifiers.functions.SMO -C 1.0 -L 0.001 -P 1.0E-12 -N 0 -V 10 -W 1 -K "weka.classifiers.functions.supportVector.RBFKernel -G 0.01 -C 250007"
```

Other than default, I changed kernel into RBFKernel to make it consistant with the R fucntion.

The result is:

```
  a  b  c   <-- classified as
 50  0  0 |  a = Iris-setosa
  0 46  4 |  b = Iris-versicolor
  0  7 43 |  c = Iris-virginica
```

**R script**:

```
library(e1071)
model <- svm(iris[,-5], iris[,5], kernel="radial", epsilon=1.0E-12)
res <- predict(model, iris[,-5])
table(pred = res, true = iris[,ncol(iris)])
```

The result is:

```
            true
pred         setosa versicolor virginica
  setosa         50          0         0
  versicolor      0         48         2
  virginica       0          2        48
```

I'm not a machine learning person, so I'm guessing the default parameters are very different for these two methods. For example, e1071 has 0.01 as default `epsilon` and WEKA has 1.0E-12. I tried to read through the manuals and wanted to make all parameters identical, but a lot of parameters do not seem comparable to me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Refer to http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/classifiers/functions/SMO.html for the RWeka parameters for SMO and use ?svm to find the corresponding parameters for e1071 svm implementation.

As per ?svm, R e1071 svm is an interface to libsvm and seems to use standard QP solvers.

> For multiclass-classification with k levels, k>2, libsvm uses the
>   ‘one-against-one’-approach, in which k(k-1)/2 binary classifiers are
>   trained; the appropriate class is found by a voting scheme.
>   libsvm internally uses a sparse data representation, which is also high-level supported by the package SparseM.

To the contrary ?SMO in RWeka

> implements John C. Platt's sequential minimal optimization algorithm
>   for training a support vector classifier using polynomial or RBF
>   kernels. Multi-class problems are solved using pairwise
>   classification.

So, these two implementations are different in general (so the results may be a little different). Still if we choose the corresponding hyper-parameters same, the confusion matrix is almost the same:

```
library(RWeka)
model.smo <- SMO(Species ~ ., data = iris,
control = Weka_control(K = list("RBFKernel", G=2), C=1.0, L=0.001, P=1.0E-12, N=0, V=10, W=1234))
res.smo <- predict(model.smo, iris[,-5])
table(pred = res.smo, true = iris[,ncol(iris)]) 

             true
pred         setosa versicolor virginica
  setosa         50          0         0
  versicolor      0         47         1
  virginica       0          3        49

library(e1071)
set.seed(1234)
model.svm <- svm(iris[,-5], iris[,5], kernel="radial", cost=1.0, tolerance=0.001, epsilon=1.0E-12, scale=TRUE, cross=10)
res.svm <- predict(model.svm, iris[,-5])
table(pred = res.svm, true = iris[,ncol(iris)])  

           true
pred         setosa versicolor virginica
  setosa         50          0         0
  versicolor      0         49         1
  virginica       0          1        49
```

Also refer to this: [https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/130293/svm-and-smo-main-differences][1] and this [https://www.quora.com/Whats-the-difference-between-LibSVM-and-LibLinear][1]

Comment: yes you are right, the kernel K will have the name of the kernel and the bandwidth gamma as list.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But for a 2-class problem, I also get two very different predictions even though I set the parameters alike. Is it because that the implementations are different?

Comment: The strategy used for multiclass classification by SVM and SMO seems to be the same (one-against-one). For binary classification, if you study all the possible parameters (including the default ones) and set all of them same, then my hunch is the results should not differ much, and if they do it's due to the implementation difference.

Comment: Thanks for replying me. I asked a similar question using a 2-class data, and the results of them seem extremely different. Could you help me take a look? Thanks in advance! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40065273/differences-of-two-class-svm-in-re1071-and-wekasmo

Comment: I have just started using R Weka, is it possible to get ROC AUC? I would appreciate any advice on this.