# Differences of two-class svm in R(e1071) and WEKA(SMO)

Tags: java, r, machine-learning, svm, weka

I generated a random data set like this:

```
set.seed(1234)
df <- data.frame(replicate(10, runif(100, 0, 1)))
df$Class <- sample(c(-1,1), 100, replace=T)
df$Class <- as.factor(df$Class)
```

It has binary classes, 100 samples and 10 features.

I tried using svm **in R** (e1071 package):

```
library(e1071)
set.seed(1234)
model <- svm(Class~.,data=df,kernel="radial",cost=1.0,tolerance=0.001,epsilon=1.0E-12,scale=TRUE,cross=10)
res <- predict(model, df[,-11])
table(pred=res, true=df[,11])  
summary(res)
summary(df$Class)
```

Then it gave me a result like:

```
    true
pred -1  1
  -1 49 13
  1   6 32
```

Originally in the data, the sample numbers of the two classes are:

```
-1  1 
55 45
```

and the model prediction gives:

```
-1  1 
62 38
```

However when I output this data into .arff file and run **with WEKA** SMO, and tried to set the same parameters as discribed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40050498/support-vector-machine-on-r-and-weka):

```
weka.classifiers.functions.SMO -C 1.0 -L 0.001 -P 1.0E-12 -N 0 -V 10 -W 1234 -K "weka.classifiers.functions.supportVector.RBFKernel -G 0.1 -C 250007"
```

All 100 predictions of WEKA is class -1, i.e. no sample is predicted to be class 1.

The two results seem extremely different.

I was wondering, if there're other parameters so different between this two methods. Or it's just totally different implementation? If it's the latter, can you please explain to me how exactly they works? I know the gist of how svm works, I just cannot imagine why they perform so differently, and am hesitate to decide which one to use.

Thank you very much.

Similar question [here](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/SVM-differences-between-R-Weka-Python-td4673586.html).

Comment: Seems pretty clear you are making some sort of error with the WEKA program. I'm not sure why you are pondering which one to use, at least with your current level of skill (or lack thereof) with WEKA. There is an RWeka package.

Comment: @42- Thanks for your reply. But I think you're just mocking others but not helping. I may not be an expert in machine learning, this is the reason why I'm asking questions here. I checked I how did weka with this data and I haven't found this sort of error. I would appreciate if you are here to help instead of sarcasm.

Comment: I was hoping you would improve the question. I didn't think that the line of code starting with `weka.classifiers.functions.SMO` told me enough about your setup to reproduce the problem. You didn't mention the RWeka package in this question, so I was a bit surprised when I found that you had loaded it in your prior question. (My level of skill with WEKA is probably lower than yours.)

Comment: @42- I think that line of code would be sufficient to reproduce the problem with weka gui. I referred to the previous question to ensure that I have picked up as many parameters as possible to make the two methods constant. I wasn't using RWeka because I had troubles installing this package. But I think it's pretty easy to convert the line of weka parameters in my question into RWeka scripts. Anyway, none of these are the main issues here. All I wanted to know is specifically how the two implementations are different.

Comment: @42- I don't have the RWeka package so I cannot check if the code is runnable. But I assume it would be this:    library(RWeka)
    model.smo <- SMO(Class ~ ., data = df,
    control = Weka_control(K = list("RBFKernel", G=0.1), C=1.0, L=0.001, P=1.0E-12, N=0, V=10, W=1234))
    res.smo <- predict(model.smo, df[,-11])
    table(pred = res.smo, true = df[,ncol(df)])

Comment: `Error in .jcall(o, "Ljava/lang/Class;", "getClass") : 
  weka.core.UnsupportedAttributeTypeException: weka.classifiers.functions.SMO: Cannot handle numeric class!`  That may be clue to the source of your error.

Comment: @42- Thanks for trying this. But the classes are not numeric, they should be binary. I did df$Class <- as.factor(df$Class) to convert them into factors, as illustrated in the question. Also, because I don't have the RWeka package, I'm not sure if I provided you with the exact right code with RWeka. If you're kind enough to use weka gui, you will generate the same results with me. Thank you.